# Filter list_filter in django admin

Tags: python, django, filter, django-admin

I need to filter by a field one to many but I just want to show related objects and not all.

is this possible, or I have to create a custom filter?

Comment: What do you mean by "just want to show related objects and not all"?

Answer (score 1):

I try to keep my templates as "dumb" as possible, so I would definitely filter my data in the view. You could try something like this:

```
filtered_results = [ row for row in results if row['key'] == 'value' ]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, and I found the solution in the link I put above